# Is it better to say "This feature allows you to..." or "This feature lets you..."?

Tags: word-choice, difference, verbs

In the context of a web application, is it better to say:

1. "This feature **allows** you to *(do something/action)*."

or

2. "This feature **lets** you *(do something/action)*."?

Comment: There's probably no difference at all.  The specific action, or larger context might change the answer, but that's doubtful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both cases are fine.

From WhatsApp [How to forward messages](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000165/):

> The Forward feature **allows you to forward** messages from a group or individual chat to another group or individual chat.

From VRScount [Pinterest’s New AR Feature Lets You ‘Try On’ Makeup Pins](https://vrscout.com/news/pinterest-ar-makeup-try-on-feature/)

> Pinterest, the popular social media platform that lets its 320 million active users worldwide everything from pin meatball recipes to the latest make-up tricks, has launched a new feature called Try On that **lets you literally “try on”** the latest new fashion trends using AR.

Comment: I'm worried that "allows you to" might be too authoritative towards the user, while "lets you" feels significantly less authoritative (in my opinion, I am not sure). What do you think?

Comment: @CharlesGaudreauJackson Well, I'm not a native speaker to state it definitively. However, based on examples I've provided it looks quite normal to use both.